# 4xx Response type not returning content

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

We are currently developing an API based on OpenAPI 3.0 and are having some troubles with OpenapiGenerator(I'll call it OAG for short). When specifying a JSON response for an error `422` for example OAG does return the specified error code but not the given JSON Response but will work for any combination of `2xx` error codes.

Now the question that comes to us is if we should not return an error code with 4xx errors OR this is a bug in OAG and we should try to fix it in their code and make a PR.

Best wishes!

Edit: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5576 for mor einformation

Comment: Which server/client do you generate? Can you post a sample OpenAPI file that others can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sure you can find all the information in this issue with code snippets: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5576